# Why is Remote Desktop Connection crashing on Win 8 Pro?

Tags: crash, connection, desktop, remote

I get "**Remote Desktop Connection has stopped working**" whenever I try to log in to one of my other computers. On my wife's computer, I don't get this error. We are both using Win 8 Pro. I compared the files "mstsc.exe" and "ntdll.dll" and they are identical on both systems. The machines I've tried to connect to are WinXP Pro systems. Here are the problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: mstsc.exe
  Application Version:  6.2.9200.16465
  Application Timestamp:    50b422f2
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.2.9200.16579
  Fault Module Timestamp:   51637f77
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000005521
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.103
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 2534
  Additional Information 2: 25341db0b9a417145dca7b48f0cbb4e4
  Additional Information 3: ea6e
  Additional Information 4: ea6ed21e26f1a51f77d040634f01c908
```

Comment: Have you updated all your drivers?  How about memory tests?  How about an running SFC?

Comment: All drivers up to date. Memory diagnostic didn't find any problems. I'm not sure what an SFC is.

Comment: Both my wife's and my computer use Webroot SecureAnywhere. Both were upgraded to Win 8 Pro in March, hers from Win 8 and mine from Win 7.